# How to append(I don't mind replacing) file in S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I am processing my data using Pyspark in AWS Glue. I would need to generate batch report after each steps (No. of Steps say 20) are completed in a date timestamp formatted file. However, at the end of the process I would like to have only the last file generated from the process. 
I can understand S3 can't have append functionality working on same file. So I would not mind with replacing the last file generated by the process. Can it be done with some simple functionality?

Comment: Not sure whether I read your question correctly but if you want to replace a file on S3 you simply write it again with the same object key and it will be replaced.

Comment: You can download the file from S3, append new data at the end(if you want to modify it) to it and upload with the same key. The object will be replaced. You can enable versioning if you need the copy of the older file.

Comment: Hi, My objective is to upload the file with date timestamp. Everytime it uploads a new timestamp generated file it should replace the previous file. At the end it would end up with only one file. Can I achieve something like this or any other alternatives?